# Does it make sense to ask : $\langle dS \rangle _t=d\langle S\rangle_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $S=(S_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a continuous local martingale.

Does it make sense to ask if in general we have : $\langle dS \rangle _t=d\langle S\rangle_t$ ?

**My supposition** :

I think if it makes sense to ask this question it is not hold true  :

If we take a standard Brownian motion $B$ we have for all $t\geq 0$ : 
$$d\langle B\rangle_t = dt$$
and
$$
\mathbb E ((dB_t)^2) = \mathbb E ((B_t-B_{t-\epsilon})^2) \text{ when } \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+
$$
then :
\begin{align}
\mathbb E ((B_t-B_{t-\epsilon})^2) &= \mathbb E (B_t^2) + \mathbb E (B_{t-\epsilon}^2) - 2\mathbb E (B_tB_{t-\epsilon}) \\
&= t+(t-\epsilon) \overset {\epsilon\rightarrow 0}{=} 2t \\
&= \langle dB\rangle_t\neq t = d\langle B\rangle_t
\end{align}

But I am not really convinced, someone may tell me if I am wrong?

Edit: Calculus wrong, look at the comments.

Comment: I'm confused by your reasoning. $E[(B_t-B_{t-\epsilon})^2]=\epsilon$ by definition of Brownian motion.

Comment: I am too confused

Comment: No need to be confused: $\langle dS \rangle _t$ simply does not exist. Recall that $dS_t$ is not a random variable but simply a notational device useful to manipulate integrals $\int_0^tX_udS_u$. Likewise, $d\langle S\rangle_t$ is not a random variable but simply a notational device useful to manipulate integrals $\int_0^tX_ud\langle S\rangle_u$.

Comment: Given a continuos local martingale $S_t$, how do you define $dS_t$?

Comment: ('contd) Thus, in the identity [$\mathbb E ((dB_t)^2) = \mathbb E ((B_t-B_{t-\epsilon})^2) \text{ when } \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$], the LHS does not exist and the limit of the RHS when $\epsilon\to0$ is $0$.

Comment: RHS = right hand side
LHS = left hand side

Comment: So, what's my error in the RHS ? why haven't I got 0 ?

Comment: ... if $B_0=0$ ?

Comment: Answer : $\mathbb E (B_tB_{t-\epsilon}) = \mathbb E (((B_t-B_{t-\epsilon})+(B_{t-\epsilon}-B_0))B_{t-\epsilon})=...$ and the result stem

Comment: Still confused, or did that pass?

Comment: Everything is ok